# How to catch 416 errors when fetching a blob using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, xmlhttprequest, blob

I have this code which attempts to fetch a blob using XMLHttpRequest and then passes it to the `resolve` of a Promise.

```
 Mixer.get_blob = ($tmp_audio) ->
    new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      blob_url = $tmp_audio.attr("src")
      xhr.open "GET", blob_url, true
      xhr.responseType = "blob"
      xhr.on
      xhr.onload = (e) ->
        if this.status == 200
          blob = this.response
          resolve(blob)
      xhr.send()
```

When the blob has some content, it works fine. The problem is when the blob is empty, I see this in my console:

[image]

However the status is still showing up as 200 so it still gets sent to the server. Why is the status not being detected correctly, and how can I catch this error? I've tried putting breakpoints in, but I can't see what line of code the error is originating from.